# Ms Access Linking To Sharepoint List

Tags: list, microsoft-access, vba

I have a SharePoint list with about 40,000 records * 4 columns
I have linked the share point list in MS Access and attempted to run a query selecting all the records in the list into a local table to allow me to build a report off of them using MS Access queries and VBA

However when i run the query i get "System.OutOfMemoryException" every time i attempt to run it. This is driving me crazy as it is the only thing stopping this report going into production

Can anyone help?
Is it because the list doesn't scale well when the number of records gets too high
Is there perhaps a VBA method that can be used in order to select the records one at a time into a local table or array on the PC

All help is greatly appreciated

Best Regards

Comment: Has anyone had any luck with this?